# NUnit runner compilation failed error with ReSharper and NUNIT

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, resharper

I have a project with 100s of tests. Some of them run fine, others just say Inconclusive - Test not run. These tests have run fine in the past. Also, I am getting the below error that I am sure is related. These tests run fine if I run them one by one.

```
2016.12.19 16:33:25.658   ERROR JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.CodeDom.CompileException: NUnit runner compilation failed
(0:0) Error generating Win32 resource: The system cannot find the path specified. 


Server stack trace: 
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.CodeDom.RunnerTypeCompiler.AssertCompilationResultsHaveNoErrors(CompilerResults compilerResults)
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.CodeDom.RunnerTypeCompiler.CompileIntoAssembly(String outputPath, Assembly resourceAssembly, String[] resourcesToCompile, String[] assembliesToReference)
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit30.DelegatingTestRunner.GetRunner(String nUnitInstallDir, TaskExecutorConfiguration configuration, SimpleLogger logger) in c:\Build Agent\work\10282fe47e6c6213\Psi.Features\UnitTesting\nUnit\Runner30\Src\DelegatingTestRunner.cs:line 70
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit30.DelegatingTestRunner.RunTests(IRemoteTaskServer server, List`1 assemblies, Dictionary`2 tests, Dictionary`2 fixtures, List`1 explicitly, Boolean useAddins, String nUnitInstallDir, TaskExecutorConfiguration configuration, SimpleLogger logger) in c:\Build Agent\work\10282fe47e6c6213\Psi.Features\UnitTesting\nUnit\Runner30\Src\DelegatingTestRunner.cs:line 43
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.PrivateProcessMessage(RuntimeMethodHandle md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.INUnitRunner.RunTests(IRemoteTaskServer server, List`1 assemblies, Dictionary`2 tests, Dictionary`2 fixtures, List`1 explicitly, Boolean useAddins, String nUnitInstallDir, TaskExecutorConfiguration configuration, SimpleLogger logger)
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.Run(String nUnitInstallDir, String assmbl, Boolean useAddins)
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.RunTestsInAssemblies(List`1 assemblies, NUnitTestAssemblySetTask assemblySetTask, Boolean useAddins, NUnitVersion nUnitVersion)
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.ExecuteRecursive(TaskExecutionNode node)
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.StartupTaskRunnerHost.Execute(TaskExecutionNode node)
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.StartupTaskRunnerHost.ExecuteNodes(IEnumerable`1 nodes)
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.TasksPacketHandler.ThreadProc(TaskRunnerProxy proxy, IEnumerable`1 packets, AssemblyLoader loader)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with the latest version ("2016.3") of Resharper. More details here... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-462284
The issue occurs when you have multiple test assemblies.

Comment: This is the ticket that was created after I submitted the bug to JetBrains. Thanks for adding it here.

Comment: Excellent... so you'll be accepting this as the correct answer then :) (P.S. it looks like it is fixed in "2016.3.1", if you restart Visual Studio after the update).